# Custom HttpModule is not called when used Server.Transfer

Tags: asp.net

I have code in my project which changes the URL containing the text as querystring to number to get the data from the database. I am checking the querystring in page load and if it contains the name rather than the number I am mapping it to the numeric key. Now I have to execute the page life cycle again. I had two choice either use the

```
        Response.Redirect
```

but I do not want the URL in the client browser to change so I went with the

```
        Server.Transfer
```

The problem I started facing is that I have a custom httpmodule which is used to log the URLs in the database. I realized that

```
         BeginRequest
```

in the http module is not firing after the

```
        Server.Transfer
```

My application is working fine in the case of

```
       Response.Redirect.
```

I am not sure how and why Server.Transfer is skipping my HttpModule and if it is how it works ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Server.Transfer` is a completely server side mechanism - it instantiates the new `Page` class based on the path to `.aspx` file and transfers the execution there (including all state information for the built-in objects). There is no new request and nothing goes again through the pipeline (so among other things HttpModules are not re-executed), as the hosting part is interested this is still the same request - the response has just been created from different page than it was originally planed.

`Response.Redirect` falls to standard HTTP mechanism. On server side it throws an exception to break the current execution pipeline and return an 3xx status code. The browser then issues new request for the resource under the new URL. Both requests go through full pipeline on the server side.

So the answer to your question boils down to the fact that `HttpModules` are being executed for every upcoming request but in case of `Server.Transfer` there is no new upcoming request.